# Need to listen to a table for changes in Firebase

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In my Angular 2 app I need to listen to a table for changes in `Firebase`. I'm using Angular2, Firebase, and TypeScript. I have a listener but it doesn't fire when I change the database table.

**I need it to always hit the listener** when the table is updated/changed.
It seems like I need to put my listener in a global place. Currently, my listener is in a service file.

**This is my attempt:**

```
this.adminNotifications = new Firebase(_environment.firebaseUrl + "/adminNotifications");

taskSchedulerListner = (): Promise<any> => { 
    this.adminNotifications.on('value', function(snapshot: any) {
        console.log("admin notification hit!");
    });
}
```

Let me know if you need to see any other code. Currently, I just want the listener to be hit when the **adminNotifications** table is changed. I other words, I want the `console.log` method in the above example to be hit.

I don't get any console errors, just nothing happens when table adminNotifications is changed.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this same problem and came to realize that you don't have to wrap your listener in a promise when returning it. Just readjust your code to this.

```
this.adminNotifications = new Firebase(_environment.firebaseUrl + "/adminNotifications");

taskSchedulerListner = this.adminNotifications.on('value', function(snapshot: any) {
        console.log("admin notification hit!");
    });
```